# How to set the value of an input of choice type using the controller when i want to edit a user in symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony6

The input is always not checked , so the admin is always obliged to check one of them knowing that the other inputs have the good values  ...
I tried this but that doesnt work;

```
#[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'app_user_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, User $user, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {


        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $form->get("gender")->setData($user->getGender());

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

//            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
//            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $userRepository->save($user, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('user/edit.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'userForm' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Is your field `gender` mapped or not in your form declaration ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux Yes it is mapped by default

Comment: You must set mapped to `false` to control your inputs in your Controller.

Comment: @VincentDecaux I tried it but that doesnt work , when I asgin the value $form->get("gender")->setData($user->getGender());  i can dd() $form gender and the value is well stored but in the edit form the field is unchecked